# NSDate showing null always

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am using `NSDate` concept in my application. In one of my classes I have set the `[NSDate date]` for a date instance and I use it in the next class.  It works perfect for me but if I use that date its giving me 5.30 hrs before time so I used a `NSDateFormatter` to change it but I'm getting a null response.

```
    NSLog(@"update date= %@",pullToRefreshManager_.pullToRefreshView.lastUpdateDate);
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:timeZone];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",pullToRefreshManager_.pullToRefreshView.lastUpdateDate];
    NSLog(@"Str== %@",str);
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str]];
    NSLog(@"exact date= %@",date);
```

console am getting out put as

```
update date= 2013-08-28 07:34:23 +0000 
  Str== 2013-08-28 07:34:23 +0000
 exact date= (null)
```

Comment: this is wat i get in my console                                   update date= 2013-08-28 07:34:23 +0000
Str== 2013-08-28 07:34:23 +0000
exact date= (null)

Comment: The formats don't match - add " Z" to the date formatter. That said, I don't see any reason why you would convert it back into a date object. The date should always stay the same here. Just use the correct formatter for *output*.

Answer (score 0):

NSDate always comes as a GMT. So you have to format the date as per your required timeZone.. You can set your device timeZOne or can use Calendar to set the timeZOne..
**UPDATED:**
Use this date format instead of this

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
```

Comment: i have given my timezone as UTC which will give you the current time zone , but its not working

Comment: Can we add this answer to a ASKED EVERY DAY category? Perhaps on top of 'ask a question'....

Answer (score 0):

in the line no.5

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +0000"];
```

and line no.8
why using NSString with format when already str is string

```
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:str];
```

Comment: it shows the result , but its ahead of 1 HR of my system time @SARFARAZ KHAN

Comment: @sumit Mundra Pls advise it shows the result , but its ahead of 1 HR of my system time

Comment: what is your system time zone and what is the actual result

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null because the date you are getting from "pullToRefreshManager_.pullToRefreshView.lastUpdateDate" might have different date format than your NSDateFormatter.

To get date from string we need same date formate of the datestring and NSDateFormatter.

Try this code :

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter1=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
formatter1.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSString *StrDate =[formatter1 stringFromDate:yourDate];
NSLog(@"String Date : %@",StrSunday);

NSDate *date = [formatter1 dateFromString:StrDate];
NSLog(@"Date : %@",date);
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of **str**?

I tried this part of the code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:timeZone];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSLog(@"exact date= %@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

and it shows the date well. Something must be null in one of the other lines.